# Keyboard automatically pressing keys in Ubuntu but not in Window

Tags: keyboard

I have a USB keyboard which works perfectly in Windows but in Ubuntu 16.04 it automatically starts typing dots (`.`).

I opened the keyboard layout but no particular key was highlighted there.

On pressing the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key also, only dots are printed.

On removing the USB keyboard, the printing of dots stops.

Any idea what to do? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: same issue.. but for me it is '-' symbol.. let me know if u r able to resolve the issue..looks like ubuntu driver problem

Comment: I'm facing pageup don't know how to fix it

Comment: same issue in 18.04... any update to fix it ??